# What is the best way to make a telephone wire in blender?

Tags: bezier-curves

I am working on a project that has a light pole and there are wires going from one pole to another. I need to try and replicate the wires as realistically as possible, but I am not sure what the best way would be. Here is an image below of what I am referring to.

[image]

Comment: If you want lots of realism then use the Cloth simulator and pin the cloth wire to each pole. Is it just the "hang" that you need or how multiple wires interact?

Comment: just the hang @rob